# Get secure spring properties from Mule FunctionalTestCase

Tags: mule

I need to access the Spring property placeholder properties from a Mule FunctionalTestCase.

I am using the secure-property-placeholder which is a wrapper around the spring property placeholder so cannot load the properties manually in my test case.

Is there a way to get them from the mule context? SO I can get the decrypted values?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but you will have to create and add a [properties accessor helper bean](https://gist.github.com/ullgren/aca46a4c9bc64403cec9#file-propertiesaccessor-java) that uses the BeanFactory to lookup the property value. After this you can get that bean from the Mule context and use it to retrieve the property value.

```
PropertiesAccessor propertiesAccessor = muleContext.getRegistry().get("propertiesAccessor");
Assert.assertEquals("expectedvalue", propertiesAccessor.getProperty("key"));
```

If you do not want to have the PropertiesAccessor bean in your production code you can put the definition of this into a separate XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<spring:beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <spring:bean id="propertiesAccessor" class="PropertiesAccessor" />    
</spring:beans>
```

And then load that together with your main mule-config xml in your FunctionalTestCase

```
@Override
protected String[] getConfigFiles() {
        return new String[] {
                        "src/main/app/mule-config.xml",
                        "src/test/resources/propertiesAccessor.xml",
        };
}
```